# How can I speed up rendering many graphs in graphviz on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, graphviz

I am writing a program that repeatedly renders many small graphs (50-100) using `dot`.  It does this by calling `dot`.  Unfortunately this process is really slow.  When I look at the activity monitor, I saw that `fontd` was consuming nearly all of the process time.  It appears that this is due to some kind of font enumeration.

Given that I'm using the SVG backend, is there any way to speed up the rendering of many graphs?

I don't believe I can do all of the graphs in one render as they must all be embedded into an automatically generated HTML page.

The following example script takes 30 seconds to run on my 2.2 GHz Core i7 (2011 MacBook Pro)

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100}
do
  dot -o tmp.svg -Tsvg <<Limit
digraph g {
  a1 -> a2;
}
Limit
done
```

Rendering a single graph such as the following (97 edges not shown) takes 0.3 seconds.

```
digraph g {
  a1 -> a2;
  a3 -> a4;
  ...
  a199 -> a200;
}
```

Comment: Trying this script on a few other computers including another Mac, confirms that there is something about this one particular computer that is causing this problem.  Are there any debugging thoughts?

Comment: Try looking at the fontconfig diagnostics to see if there is anything on the machine that is causing slower than usual enumeration.